# debugging - is there checkpoint feature for windows debuggers?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, debugging

Is there a windows (win32, .net) debugger which can do something like gdb checkpoint?

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Checkpoint_002fRestart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest feature I've heard of on Windows is [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx). Another doc is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915%28VS.100%29.aspx

The feature has a lot of limitations - no 64bit, native code, script or SQL CLR support